# How to save the next and the current frame from video

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to subtract the `current` frame of video from the `previous` frame of same video , and do the same thing for all video and than `write those frame as seprate video` , I am confusing at saving the current frame and than next frame . How to save them so when the next frame come it become previous for the next frame

```
    IplImage* skipNFrames(CvCapture* capture, int n)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(cvQueryFrame(capture) == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    else
    {

        char* New_image;
     // New_image* =  cvQueryFrame(capture) - cvCloneImage(capture);
Mat current_frame;
Mat previous_frame;

if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    return -1;
}

while(1)
{
    capture >> current_frame;
    if (current_frame.empty())
        break;
    // do video processing

    imshow("Window", current_frame);
    waitKey(10);
    frame = skipNFrames(capture, 1)
    frame.copyTo(previous_frame); 

      int frame_width=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);     
      int frame_height=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);   
      int fps = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS ); 
   //creating video writer structure
     CvVideoWriter *writer = 0;
     writer=cvCreateVideoWriter("savedVideo.avi",CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'),fps,cvSize(frame_width,frame_height),1);

     if( !writer ) {
   //release memory
       cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
       return 0;
      }

    while(true) {
             //grab and retrieve each frames of the video sequentially 
             IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( New_image );
             if( !frame ) break;

       //writing frame by frame to the output file 
      cvWriteFrame(writer,frame);
   }


    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

    return 0;
}

    }
     // return cvNew_image      
    //return cvQueryFrame(capture);
} 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("try.avi");
    char buffer[1000];
    int flag=0;
    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    do
    {
        //frame = skipNFrames(capture, 1);
        cvNamedWindow("frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("frame", frame);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        char *str=new char[50];
        flag++;
        sprintf(str,"%d",flag);
        strcat(str," frame");
        strcat(str,".png");
        Mat image=frame;
        imwrite(str,image);
    } while( frame != NULL );

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("frame");
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's example using newer OpenCV 2.x interface. Also, in your code you use both `IplImage` and `Mat`. In general, use C++ interface of OpenCV unless you have to use C.

```
VideoCapture cap;
Mat current_frame;
Mat previous_frame;
Mat result;    

cap.open(0);
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "can not open camera or video file" << endl;
    return -1;
}

while(1)
{
    cap >> current_frame;
    if (current_frame.empty())
        break;

    if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
        // subtract frames
        subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, result);
    }


    imshow("Window", result);
    waitKey(10);

    frame.copyTo(previous_frame); 
}
```

Comment: Where you comment do video processing , here i start writing the video as new video ?

Comment: I just wanted show you how to save current frame and previous frame so it is available in your loop, since that was your question.  Yes, you can write frame to file or do whatever you processing you need there. Also, in the first iteration `previous_frame` is not initialized, so you will need to make sure you don't use it (only in the first iteration).

Comment: I updated my code , If you visit it , please , than just point out my mistake , so i manage it , as i am new to opencv

Comment: What is not clear about my code? Myabe you should get a book on opencv or programming. Please be specific with your question.  I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. what exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I am difficulty in using your code , as i write and take different frame through function and call it from main

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Mean where to add your code in my program , as i use mix interface of c , c++ its confusing me , well i am doing practice on opencv , i am in learning phase and using bradski book

Comment: you are mixing IplImage and Mat. Try to use only Mat and avoid older IplImage.

Comment: I guess, I don't know what you are trying to achieve in your code.

Comment: I want to remove the current frame of the video from the previous frame and write that frame which i gt from subtraction as new video , so their background will be removed

Comment: what do you mean by "remove current frame of the video from the previous frame". Are you subtracting previous frame from the current frame? What are you writing to write to the output?

Comment: When i subtract the previous frame from the current frame of the whole video , so i have alot of frames as output , i write those frames as new video , so i can analyse the changes in frame and video

Comment: sorry it is subtracting not removing

Comment: is it the function skipNFrames() that does frame subtracting? Are you sure the function works as expected? Try to test just this function and make sure it returns correct result. Also try to test and see if writing video to file works as expected as well. Try to debug your program.

Comment: There may also be a problem with your writer=cvCreateVideoWriter("savedVideo.avi",CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'),fps,cvSize(frame_width,frame_height),1); make sure that the file is opened for writing successfully. Your code looks like a mess right now. It's hard for me to help you without just rewriting everything from scratch

Comment: also in the main program you have two VideoCapture classes, one that's capturing frames from file try.avi and another that's grabbing frames from web camera. Why?

Comment: I don't see where you subtract the frames

Comment: Thats why i post code here because function skipNFrames() not work as expected , and as i mention in my code that its not subtracting the frame , these are the problem which i am facing , if i don't have these problem than why i post it here

Comment: and yes in the main program there are two videocapture classes , one was added by me and one after i enter your code in it , now i make it clear

Comment: you code does not even attempt to do what it you say it should. It makes zero cense to me. I can't help you here. I'm not going to rewrite everything for you. I have not idea what you're doing in skipNFrames(), it's just gibberish. I tried to point to into the right direction. I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: assume that i am just subtracting the frames